# Apply simple math multiple times without a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
  a <- 100
  m <- 25
  n <- 4
  temp <- copy(a)
  for(i in 1:n){
    r[i] <- (temp - m)
    temp <- r[i]
  }
```

Where `a` is a starting value, `m` is what value is subtracted from `a` and `n` is how many times `m` is subtracted from `a`.
I currently have the code in a `for` loop, which works fine, but if I wanted to use something like `vapply` could that handle this? The result `r` is a vector of the resulting values.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `r <- seq(a-m, by=-m, length.out=n)`?

Comment: what is `copy(a)` ?

Comment: @MrFlick can you please post as an answer

Comment: @RonakShah `copy(a)` was to perform a 1 time deep copy of the initial variable into a `temp` variable for compuations

Comment: @KAS when I try to do `copy(a)` it gives me an error `Error in copy(a) : could not find function "copy"`

Comment: @RonakShah I am sorry about that, I didn't even realize that was part of a package. `library(data.table)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to create a sequence with a particular step. You can do that with the `seq()` function. For example

```
r <- seq(a-m, by=-m, length.out=n)
r
# [1] 75 50 25  0
```